# Emscripten Link static Library error: wasm streaming compile fail: Import 'env.getTempRet0'

Tags: c++, linker, emscripten, webassembly

There is an error when I tried to link my wasm code with static libraries, Grassroot DICOM library.

First of all, I compile Grassroot DICOM using cmake with external toolchain and cmake found from
/1.38.14/cmake/Modules/Platform

using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 8.1 SDK.

After compile is done. I got static link files

```
libgdcmcharls.a
libgdcmCommon.a
libgdcmDICT.a
libgdcmDSED.a
....
```

Then I linked those files to my code using flag

```
-L<PATH-to-library>
-lgdcmcharls -lgdcmCommon -lgdcmDICT -lgdcmDSED ...
```

also use:

```
-s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1
```

The libraries can link and cannot compile. The errors are

> multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: """ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 121, in worker
>       result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "C:\Users\I-w-I\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 44, in mapstar
>       return list(map(*args))   File "C:\workspace\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.14\tools\shared.py", line 1363, in
>   extract_archive_contents
>       assert not os.path.dirname(f) AssertionError .

Then I changed the way that I linked to Grassroot DICOM using

```
-s RUNTIME_LINKED_LIBS=['gdcmcharls.a']
-s RUNTIME_LINKED_LIBS=['gdcmCommon.a']
-s RUNTIME_LINKED_LIBS=['gdcmDICT.a']
-s RUNTIME_LINKED_LIBS=['gdcmDSED.a']
.....
```

I get the error messages

> wasm streaming compile failed: LinkError: Import 'env.getTempRet0' is
>   invalid. Expected type Function
>
> falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

and in the console shows this error

> LinkError: Import 'env.getTempRet0' is invalid. Expected type Function

Just about my machine. I use Windows10 64-bit and
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 1.38.14
I serched online but it seems noone faces the same problem as me

### Update

now I removed all dynamic link flag and the new problem arises

```
emcc -std=c++17 -O3 --no-heap-copy -s WASM=1  -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -o hello.html  -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap']"        libgdcmcharls.bc libgdcmCommon.bc libgdcmDICT.bc libgdcmDSED.bc libgdcmexpat.bc libgdcmIOD.bc libgdcmjpeg12.bc libgdcmjpeg16.bc libgdcmjpeg8.bc libgdcmMEXD.bc libgdcmMSFF.bc libgdcmopenjp2.bc libgdcmzlib.bc libsocketxx.bc main.cpp  -o hello.js
```

> multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: """
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 121, in worker
>       result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 44, in mapstar
>       return list(map(*args))   File "C:\workspace\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.14\tools\shared.py", line 1364, in
>   extract_archive_contents
>       assert not os.path.dirname(f) AssertionError """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\workspace\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.14\emcc.py", line 3092, in
>   
>       sys.exit(run())   File "C:\workspace\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.14\emcc.py", line 1699, in run
>       final = shared.Building.link(linker_inputs, DEFAULT_FINAL, force_archive_contents=force_archive_contents,
>   temp_files=misc_temp_files, just_calculate=just_calculate)   File
>   "C:\workspace\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.14\tools\shared.py", line 2011, in
>   link
>       Building.read_link_inputs([x for x in files if not x.startswith('-')])   File
>   "C:\workspace\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.14\tools\shared.py", line 1852, in
>   read_link_inputs
>       object_names_in_archives = pool.map(extract_archive_contents, archive_names)   File
>   "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 268, in map
>       return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()   File
>   "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 657, in get
>       raise self._value AssertionError gmake: *** [build] Error 1

It seems the problem that python cannot find the module inside the library files

when I traced where the errors are

They are from Python function called

```
# This function creates a temporary directory specified by the 'dir' field in
# the returned dictionary. Caller is responsible for cleaning up those files
# after done.
def extract_archive_contents(archive_file):


assert not os.path.dirname(f)  #This line causes the trouble
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use [`RUNTIME_LINKED_LIBS`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/settings.js) option should look like this:

```sh
-s RUNTIME_LINKED_LIBS=['gdcmcharls.a', 'gdcmCommon.a', 'gdcmDICT.a', 'gdcmDSED.a']
```

However, this may not be the solution you want. Because you want statically linking the the libraries, not dynamically.

The correct way to compile them together is just to include them as compile targets. The complete `emcc` option will look like this:

```
emcc --other-options-you-use \
     -s WASM=1 \
     gdcmcharls.a \
     gdcmCommon.a \
     gdcmDICT.a \
     gdcmDSED.a \
     your_other_source_files_1.c \
     your_other_source_files_2.cpp \
     -o output.js
```

Don't use [`-s SIDE_MODULE=1`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/settings.js) flag. This is for dynamic linking. `-s EXPORT_ALL=1` is probably not you want neither.

Comment: I am not sure about the way that I compile the code make this problem. I compile using Visual studio Release 32 bit  and also test with Release 64bit. but both does not work too

Comment: No. You are not supposed to use any of MS toolchains nor Unix, but Emscripten's compilers. You should enable [Emscripten SDK](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) before any compile.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that is the problem.

Comment: @MooMoo No problem. So 1. Enable emscripten environment by `source ./emsdk_env.sh`. 2. Run CMake by `emconfigure cmake` (not just cmake!) 3. Run make by `emmake make` (not just make!). Take a look at the [doc here](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html).